# Java printf using variable field size?

Tags: java, string, formatting, printf

I'm just trying to convert some C code over to Java and I'm having a little trouble with `String.printf`.

In C, to get a specific width based on a variable, I can use:

```
printf("Current index = %*d\n", sz, index);
```

and it will format the integer to be a specific size based on `sz`.

Trying:

```
System.out.println(String.format("Current index = %*d\n", sz, index));
```

results in an error since it doesn't like the `*`.

I currently have the following kludge:

```
System.out.println(String.format("Current index = %" + sz + "d\n", index));
```

but I'm hoping there's a slightly better way, yes?

Comment: Using println(String.format) is redundant. You should use printf method.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Declare an extra variable before using `printf`:

```
String format = "%" + fieldSize + "d";
System.out.printf(format, yourVariables);
```

(this is the first solution I found from a web search)

Comment: This is basically the same way he has done, except you're doing the same thing in two lines.

Comment: I’m sorry, I don’t see how this answer is useful, as it adds exactly nothing to the question.

Answer (score 2):

This is arguably no better than your "kludge", but here's a method you can embed into the call to  `printf` that will substitute widths for the asterisks that you pass to it. Its result is used as the real format.
For example, consider this call:

```
System.out.printf("%04d %2s %-7d;%n", 65, "a", 6);
```

I will replace the first and third widths via an embedded function:

```
System.out.printf( wf("%0*d %2s %-*d;%n", 4, 7), 65, "a", 6);
```

And here's the code:

```
public static String wf(String fmt, int... widths) {
    return metaWidthFormat('*', fmt, widths);
}

public static String metaWidthFormat(char wmeta, String fmt, int ... widths) {
    if (fmt == null) return null;
    int wix = 0;
    boolean outside = true;
    // initial capacity is sufficient for each substituted width to be 2 digs
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(fmt.length() + widths.length);
    for (char ch : fmt.toCharArray()) {
        if (outside) {
            result.append(ch);
            outside = (ch != '%');
        } else {
            if (ch == wmeta) {
                result.append(widths[wix++]);
            } else {
                result.append(ch);
            }
            outside = (ch == wmeta) || (ch == '%') || Character.isAlphabetic(ch);
        }
    }
    return result.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Presuming that index fits inside sz you can do something like:

```
char[] temp = new char[sz];
Arrays.fill(temp, '0');
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(new String(temp));
System.out.println(String.format("Current index = %s\n", df.format(index)));
```

Note, by not using `Format` or any of its subclasses, there is no `Locale` dependent characters like ' ', '.' or ',' added to the output.

Answer (score -1):

maybe it's too late but putting it here for others

```
int width = 5;
int precision = 2;
float f = 12.34567f;
System.out.printf("%"+width+"."+precision+"f%n",f);
```

tested in java 1.8

Comment: @tilde not exactly, please take some time comparing difference

Comment: No, not exactly. You also set the precision. But the substance is the same - first, define the format string with +, then pass it to printf.