# variable/parameterized width for printf/format in Java (using * or something else?)

Tags: java, printf, string-formatting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java printf using variable field size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550123/java-printf-using-variable-field-size)

I haven't worked with Java in a while so I was looking for a way to
specify *variable* width in `format`/`printf` when formatting/printing output. My example shows the use with an integer, but of course I'd like this to work for other types too.

E.g., something along the lines of

```
int val = 8;
int wid = 5;

System.out.printf("%"*d\n", wid, val);
```

I could use this work-around, which is ugly:

```
System.out.printf("%"+wid+"d\n", val);
```

Was the `*` variable field width specifier removed from Java? This old'ish
[page](http://www.sharkysoft.com/archive/printf/docs/javadocs/lava/clib/stdio/doc-files/specification.htm), section 1.3.1,
shows the use (like it would be used in C), but I can't get it to
work,  resulting in:

```
java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = '*'
```

nor have I been able to find more recent references that this
does work.

Is there an easier way to do this other than my work-around above?

I did look around before posting and came across this about 2-year old SO question [Java printf using variable field size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550123/java-printf-using-variable-field-size) but is that the final word on this?

Answer (score 0):

The general syntax of a format specifier is

> %[parameter][flags][width][.precision][length]type

Instead of printf, you can also use

> String.format("%"+wid+"d",val);

And yes, these are the only ways in case you are using a Java Formatter.