# Losing magic numbers in Java printf format specifiers to generate columns

Tags: java, printf, magic-numbers

In C, the `printf` function has a great wildcard feature, where you can use an asterisk where you would normally place an int that specifies minimum column width. So you can go

```
#DEFINE COL_WIDTH 20;
```

up in the preprocessor directives, and then later you can put

```
printf("%*s", COL_WIDTH, myString);
```

to print myString in a 20 character column.

This asterisk trick doesn't seem to be implemented in Java. I have to go

```
printf("%20s", myString);
```

instead. This is a flagrant magic number, especially if you are trying to use printf to do something like build a table where you want an easy way to change the column width on a lot of lines at once. So,

- is there something I'm missing about printf in Java that makes what I want to do possible, or
- is there a neat and more Java-like way of formatting text for output in a table without using magic numbers?

Comment: You can sprintf the format string :-)

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550123/java-printf-using-variable-field-size

Comment: Genius! Thanks Balduz and Marko. THe trick is to build the format string with variables.

Comment: `String myFormatString = "%" + COL_WIDTH + "s"; printf (myFormatString, myString);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`printf("%"+COL_WIDTH+"s", myString);`

Comment: Thanks Steven! I'll use this in C too; it will make printf statements a lot more readable if I'm not feeding them column width constants in the arguments list.

Comment: anybody care to say why this was downvoted...?