# SonarQube issue raised on use of string formatter

Tags: java, sonarqube

SonarQube is raising an issue on my string formatter use:

> Format specifiers should be used instead of string concatenation.

I have used below java code to add padding 0 in the number.

```
int paddingLength = seqLength - seqNoLength;
String.format("%0" + paddingLength + "d", seqNo);
```

Comment: Because format strings are interpreted at runtime, rather than validated by the Java compiler, they can contain errors that lead to unexpected behavior or runtime errors.

Comment: Any alternative way to ignore this sonar issue?

Comment: Format the formatString ?

Comment: Yes. Any other best way to achieve the same

Comment: From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550123/java-printf-using-variable-field-size) it appears that what you are doing is fine.

Comment: @Novaterata it would be ok for SonarQube to give this warning if it was something like `String.format("%s", "N: " + seqNo)` but in this case SonarQube is overzealous. You can't do much better than `String.format("%0" + paddingLength + "d", seqNo)`. The alternative, `String.format(String.format("%%0%dd", paddingLength), seqNo)`, is much worse than the original. SonarQube ought to suppress this warning when concatenation is used for format specifiers.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou You're right. I totally missed that they were actually concatenating the formatting

Answer (score 4):

The issue is raised because you're passing a concatenated string to your formatter. If you're going to use string formatting, then *use* string formatting:

```
int paddingLength = seqLength - seqNoLength;
String fmt = String.format("%%0%dd", paddingLength);
String.format(fmt, seqNo);
```

Or even

```
int paddingLength = seqLength - seqNoLength;
String.format(String.format("%%0%dd", paddingLength), seqNo);
```

Although the first version is far more readable.

Comment: Thanks @Novaterata. Fixed

Comment: I've just re-examined the documentation and tried it. It doesn't seem you can do this.

Comment: Misunderstood the intent originally @KlitosKyriacou. See my change.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Your changed code works well. However, I'm not convinced that this is clearer than, or has any advantage over, the original code that used concatenation. I presume the SonarQube warning exists because there are advantages to String.format compared to concatenation when it comes to e.g. internationalization. However, this applies mostly to text that is ultimately going to be output by the application. On the other hand, format syntax is not going to be output at all; it should be seen as part of the program code, and not be subject to this warning.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou if this were your code, I'd advise you to mark the issue "Won't Fix". As it stands tho I'm not the only one who missed the intent of the original code. So off-hand I'd say my first code snippet is superior merely because it makes the intent crystal clear.